# Validating Input for Numeric Range 1300 to 1500? (Using Regex or other common method.)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms, string-parsing

I want to validate that a user input string has a number range from **1300 to 1500**.

I tried `Regex regxUsrInput = new Regex(@"^(?:[1-9]|1|3[0-9]|0[0-9]|0[0-9]|1500)$");`

.. but this does not validate the way I expected.

I am open to any suggestions, including alternatives. Thanks

If it matters: My application is a **Windows Forms** application written in **C#**. The user input is coming from a standard **TextBox Control**.

Comment: Do you really need a regex for this? Why not `if(input >= 1300 && input <= 1500)`?

Comment: You're using a regex to solve a problem.  Now you have two problems.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But I have to validate that input must be digits and validate the range as well.

Comment: What type of data is your input? Where are you getting the data from? ASP.Net? WinForms? something else?

Comment: If you're needing to validate that it's numeric, you can try to cast the string to an int or double.  Use Integer.TryParse() or Double.TryParse() - they return false if the cast fails.

Comment: Parse != Casting @Jeff

Comment: @KingCronus: Really?  I'm off to do some reading, then.  That said, it's close enough for most purposes.  From the POV of the end user, it doesn't make much of a difference if it's a cast or not, I expect.

Comment: I want to ask why it is not recommended to use regex in my condition? specific reason?

Comment: @AbdulAziz because there are far easier, more readable ways to achieve what you want to do. Why make your code harder to maintain for no discernible reason?

Comment: Abdul, it's mostly about maintainability.  Sure, you can put in a regex to recognize 1300-1500.  What happens when the business rules change and the limits change to 1301 and 1475?  Or 1200 and 1675?  If you use a Parse to ensure it's an integer and numerical comparison for your limits, this is an easy change.  With regex?  Not so much.

Comment: Agreed with @Jeff, don't overcomplicate things, you will kick yourself for it in the long run. Or the person who has to maintain your code will kick you. One of the two.

Comment: I wouldn't kick him, I would just rewrite it, check it in and kick him an e-mail in private to let him know I improved some of his code. Isn't that what.. everyone.. does? *looks around*

Answer (score 13):

Why are you going to use `Regex`? what about this simple method:

```
int value;
if(int.TryParse(yourTexbox.Text, out value))
{
    if(1300 < value && value < 1500)
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: I would advise actually adding the checking, rather than just considering it. Perhaps a quick Regex check? ;)

Comment: I would strongly suggest using int.TryParse instead here, as far as I am aware, OP hasn't mentioned decimal places?

Answer (score 7):

Note: don't do that. But here's how:

```
^1([34]\d{2}|500)$
```

Comment: This is entirely correct.  It's also entirely correct that you should never validate using this method.

Comment: I like how this "now-you-have-two-problems" regex solution is correct, but the "just do a simple tryparse" solution getting all the upvotes is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks it really worked. But I want to ask why it is not recommended to use regex in my condition?

Comment: @AbdulAziz: Regex is unnecessary in this case.  What you have is a very simple problem which can be solved with simple parsing and numerical comparisons, and doesn't require string pattern matching.  Regex arguably hurts maintainability (what happens when your max value changes to 1675?) and could potentially be a performance hit (though that's unlikely in this case).

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Regex_For_Range](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range) generator, your regex should be:

`^1([34][0-9]{2}|500)$`

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have pointed out that you don't need regex for this, but - for the sake of completeness - if you really want to, try this:

```
@"^1([34][0-9][0-9]|500)$"
```